# Assign shopify liquid variables inside conditional statements

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've written the following code

```
        {% case NAME %}
         {% when "abc" %}
          {% assign varOne = "123" %}
          {% assign varTwo = "345" %}
         {% when "bac" %}
          {% assign varOne = "321" %}
          {% assign varTwo = "543" %}
        {% endcase %}
        
       <p>{{ varOne }}</p>
       <p>{{ varTwo }}</p>
```

i wanted to know if shopify allows me to set values like this inside a conditional block in shopify liquid and use them outside the conditional block? are there any scope related implications for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Shopify allow to use {% assign %} method inside conditional {% case %} statements.

```
{% assign food = 'cake' %}

{% case food %}
{% when 'cake' %}
    {% assign isTasty = 'true' %}
{% when 'carrot' %}
    {% assign isTasty = 'false' %}
{% endcase %}

{{ isTasty }}
```

This will return **'true'**

Comment: Not sure if it's worth adding to your answer, but with respect to `are there any scope related implications for the same?` the main scoping considerations are: * A variable declared inside a section is only accessible inside that section, and * When using `render` to display snippets, variables declared inside the snippet are only accessible inside that snippet.